# Javascript transforming borders with headers

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table

I locked the table headers through

```
onScroll={() => { 
  document.querySelector('thead').style.transform = 
  `translate(0,${this.scrollRef.scrollTop}px)`; 
}}
```

but when i scroll the table, the header borders do not stick to the headers.

How do i make the borders stay on the headers when scrolling?

Comment: @meagar, most `react` and `angular` questions do not contain a [mcve] inside the question itself on [so]. Unlike this one, most do not even contain a link to an example at all. Should they all be closed as off-topic? I personally find this one having a clear problem statement and being therefore answerable, most likely useful for future visitors with a similar problem.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu yes, they should. Questions here cannot depend on links to Github repos or any other off-site resource. If the question can't be asked without directing users to a test site you've set up, the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. "Answerable" is not our criteria for on-topic.

Comment: Edited question to remove off-site references

Comment: @meagar some libraries add complexity to the task of creating a snippet. Between not having an example at all and having a live example with specific information on what the problem is, many times, that is the difference between understanding the question and not. Let me put it this way: if I found the question in current form, I wouldn't have answered, as I had no way of knowing for sure whats' the cause. For all I care, it's `react`. So it's shadow DOM. I don't use `react` that much. Could have been from `position:fixed` but why chance an answer if I can't be sure? I'd have passed.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You shouldn't have answered the question in its current form *or* its previous form. It was and still is off-topic. The actual MCVE here would have nothing to do with react, and linking to an entire React app is *exactly* the wrong thing to do here. We want self-contained questions containing **minimal** examples, period.

Comment: @meagar, I already [realized it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354573/is-answerable-a-criteria-for-being-on-topic-on-so). There's a comment of mine there which says: *"The problem is I answered the question"*. But, as you can see, setting a question as off-topic after it has an accepted answer is highly unlikely to improve its chances of becoming on topic or more useful for future visitors. Now it's completely nonsensical and nobody will ever spend the necessary time to make it useful. It should probably be deleted. Thank you for pointing all this out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your problem:

```css
thead th {
  position:relative;
}
thead th:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

And no, JavaScript is not transforming borders. The problem is the borders are not actually part of the `<th>` element because they're collapsed.

Internally, the browser checks on adjacent elements to determine combined borders. Those borders are positioned without taking into account `transform`s applied to `<th>` elements, but their *initial* position in DOM.

Easiest solution is to use `:before` pseudo-element to draw the borders.

---

The other solution would be to override

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

on your `<table>`, applied by `bootstrap.css`.
But this will mean your table borders will no longer be collapsed (combined) and, most probably, you don't want that.